# Выводить сообщение если скрипт не работает

Tags: javascript, php

Есть веб-скада , есть ли пример что при отключении сети или когда нет сигнала то скрипт выдает ошибку подключения? Вот вроде что-то похожее но не знаю подходит ли или нет ...

Вот здесь нужно сделать проверку ,а если нет ответа то выдавать сообщение об ошибке

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        inform = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    nmbr = inform.length;
    console.log('answer = ' + xmlhttp.responseText);        
    console.log('you have nmbr = ' + nmbr);         

    for (i = 0; i < nmbr; i++) {

        if(element = mapContDoc.getElementById(inform[i].obj)){ x = 'obj is on page' ;}
        else {x = 'err - there is not on page' ;}
        if (inform[i].obj=="end") { x = 'end of answer' ;}
        console.log('obj = ' + inform[i].obj + '  /  type = ' + inform[i].type + '  /  ' + x);

        if(x == "obj is on page"){

            // ТИП 1. изменение цвета, толщ.линий
            if (inform[i].type == "1") {   
                element.setAttribute('type', inform[i].type);
                element.setAttribute('color', inform[i].color);
               element.setAttribute('blnk',  inform[i].blnk);
            } 



            // ТИП 4. изменение цвета, содержание
            if (inform[i].type == "4") {   
                element.setAttribute('type', inform[i].type);
                element.setAttribute('font', inform[i].font);
                element.setAttribute('txt',  inform[i].txt);
            }


        }
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: <?php
function ping($ip){
    $output = shell_exec("ping $ip");
    var_dump(iconv("cp866","utf-8", $output));
}
ping('192.168.0.1');

?>

Comment: Так скрипт не работает или отсутствует подключение к сети?

Comment: вначале пингуй, а потом выполняй действие если все норм

Comment: [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-status) - оно, не оно? А то метка `php` вводит в заблуждение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для проверки текущего статуса соединения  можно использовать

```
if(navigator.onLine) { // true|false
// ...}
```

для  того что бы отловить изменение  состояния  сети  можно -

```
function updateIndicator() {
    // Show a different icon based on offline/online
}

// Update the online status icon based on connectivity
window.addEventListener('online',  updateIndicator);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateIndicator);
updateIndicator();
```

но  это даст возвожность проверить есть ли у клиента вообще соединение.
а для проверки  соединения с сервером нужно уже пинговать. 
Например можно отправлять какой-то запрос на сервер и в случае ошибки выводить  ошибку. на примере fetsch:

```
  fetch(ping_url).then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
      return response.data;
    }
    throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    //bla bla
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(
      "There has been a problem with your connection: " + error.message
    );
  });
```

в catch   уже делаем то что нам нужно.